# Vaadin 8 grid with multiple filters

Tags: java-8, vaadin8

I want to filter grid content according to two filtering criterias, therefore I have the following

```
ListDataProvider<Person> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<Person>) grid.getDataProvider();
SerializablePredicate<Person> filter = new SerializablePredicate<Person>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(Person Person) {
    return false;
  }
};

filter.and(Person -> Person.getAge() == 30);
filter.and(Person -> Person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bernd"));
dataProvider.setFilter(filter);
```

}

However, the grid does not show anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjunction always evaluates to `false` because it is modeled like:

```
false && Person.getAge() == 30 && Person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bernd")
```

Either you're using return `true` in the first filter, or you ommit it and start with `Person.getAge() == 30`.

Second problem is that you're ignoring the results of your conjunction. In addition to this, the method `and` is defined in `Predicate` and returns a non-serializable `Predicate`. Solution would be to use a simple `&&`.

```
SerializablePredicate<Person> filter = p -> p.getAge() == 30 &&
                                            p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bernd");
```

Comment: I have just used return true. the result is that the filters does not get evaluated

Comment: As I said you're ignoring the return-values of your conjunction. See my edit and try to use the new `SerializablePredicate`.

Comment: Btw I wouldn't recommend naming the lambda parameter exactly the same as your class. This might be confusing because one could think that you access the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems.
First one:

The function

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other)
```

returns a new predicate.

```
ListDataProvider<Person> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<Person>) 

grid.getDataProvider();
SerializablePredicate<Person> filter = new SerializablePredicate<Person>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(Person Person) {
    return true;
  }
};

filter = filter.and(Person -> Person.getAge() == 30);
filter = filter.and(Person -> Person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bernd"));
dataProvider.setFilter(filter);
```

The other problem is, that ListDataProvider expected a SerializablePredicate.

You can extend the SerializiablePredicate

```
public interface ExtendedSerializablePredicate<T> extends SerializablePredicate<T> {

    default ExtendedSerializablePredicate<T> and(ExtendedSerializablePredicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}
```

now you can use this:

```
ListDataProvider<Person> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<Person>) 

grid.getDataProvider();
ExtendedSerializablePredicate<Person> filter = new ExtendedSerializablePredicate<Person>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(Person Person) {
    return true;
  }
};

filter = filter.and(Person -> Person.getAge() == 30);
filter = filter.and(Person -> Person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bernd"));
dataProvider.setFilter(filter);
```